# Reasons why does the os have only limited information about the layout of data on hard disks

Tags: storage

Do someone knows some reasons why the os has only limited informations about the layout of data on hard disks(with regard to locality)?

Comment: You may want to rephrase this one. It's still Unix-specific (kind of) but may be considered to broad to be able to answer properly.

Comment: This was actually asked like that from an assignment-.

Comment: Well if that's the case then my best effort response may be good enough. I would just summarize it as the OS often having too abstract of a view of how the data is saved. If it's that vague of a question, they're probably only interested in knowing you know the fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

The OS *is* actually able to more or less reliably determine locality for local HDD's.

It's only for stuff like SAN LUN's or some RAID set ups that this is an issue because the physical HDD/SSD is attached to some *other* OS/Firmware which then presents to the consuming OS however it wants. The sequential data on a SAN LUN *may* be sequential at the HDD level (or at least kind of) but the initial OS has no way of knowing when or even if that's true.

So the OS that mounts the volume doesn't know for sure what the locality is on the underlying device, it just knows the locality for the space as presented by the other system. Locality at that abstract of a level doesn't matter much beyond reducing IOPS by merging requests.